# Connecting to HBase using Rest Services

Tags: json, rest, hbase

I followed the tutorial and tried communicating to HBase using JSON and Rest Services.

I am using the cloudera distribution CDH4.6
The HBase version in this is hbase-0.94.15+86

I called the following link(60000 is the port where HBase is running on the CDH4 VMware Machine. location is the name of the table)

```
http://192.168.26.128:60000/location (using get)
```

This is mentioned in the following link, that this should get all the table data in JSON format

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/JSONRest

I got the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch>Server IPC version 3 cannot communicate with 
client version 47
```

I am not able to understand where the mismatch is happening? Am I doing something( or might be everything) wrong? Please point me in the correct direction
Also, is the REST Service, already installed on the CDH or do we have to install it? An elaborate answer on the basics or any link to a document explaining the very basic step by step would be very much helpful.
I have been trying to google and found a lot of stuffs, but nothing was able to make things work for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the hbase version you are using? and the link you provided is quite old. try this one - "http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html"

Comment: @Chandrakant, thanks for the new link. I have updated the question accordingly. Kindly help with further inputs.